# Implementing the Wald Test in PEST Procedure

Tags: matlab, likelihood-ratio, wald-test

I'm trying to code a [PEST](http://drsmorey.org/bibtex/upload/Taylor:Creelman:1967.pdf) sequence in MATLAB but am unsure about how and when the Wald test is actually implemented. Having read the MATLAB [help page](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/econ/conduct-a-wald-test.html) for the test,  I think my confusion lies with what the correct restriction function should be.

"A Wald test to aim at any desired target
probability is very easy to construct for PEST.

Starting anew with each change in testing level, the
experimenter keeps a running count of the number of
correct responses N (C) and the total number of trials T.
After each trial, the test defines permissible upper and
lower bounds on N(C). If N(C) falls between these
bounds, another trial is made at the same testing level.
If N(C) falls on or above the upper bound, the decision
is that the current level is too high, and if N(C) is on or
below the lower bound, the current level is taken to
be too low.

If the current testing level were exactly Lt, the expected
number of correct trials E[N(C)] = Pt X T, after
T trials. The sequential test bounds are given by the
expected number of events plus and minus a constant.
where Nb(C) is the bounding number of events after T
trials, and W is a constant, called the deviation limit of
the sequential test."

Would the function be E[N(C)] = P x T, or Nb(C) = E[N(C)] + W?

p.s. I've never used a Wald test before nor know what a Jacobian is so pardon me if the question seems rather obvious.

Comment: Please include whatever information and context is necessary to understand and answer your question in the body of the question. People aren't going to want to navigate elsewhere and read stuff just to answer your question for you. Also be aware that questions about code (eg, MATLAB) are off topic here, and it isn't clear if that might be what you're after.

Comment: I am not asking about code. I am asking about the correct equation to be using for a Wald test.

Comment: @GendouH you need to explain where the Wald test comes into play here

Comment: @ssdecontrol I think it comes into play in deciding whether or not E[N(C)] falls between Nb(C) = E[N(C)] + W and Nb(C) = E[N(C)] - W or outside of those.